# Fullcalendar rerender events

Tags: jquery, events, checkbox, fullcalendar, rerender

I'm trying to rerender removed elements on my calendar (Fullcalendar.io) but isnt working.

Here's the code:

```
        $("#check1").click(function(){
            if($('#check1').prop('checked')) {
                $("#calendar").fullCalendar('rerenderEvents', 'id1');
            } else {
                $("#calendar").fullCalendar('removeEvents', 'id1');
            }
        });
        $("#check2").click(function(){
            if($('#check2').prop('checked')) {
                $("#calendar").fullCalendar('rerenderEvents', 'id2');
            } else {
                $("#calendar").fullCalendar('removeEvents', 'astronomia');
            }
        });
```

I've tried refetchEvents, renderEvent, addEventSource, clientEvent and updateEvent none of them worked.
How can I solve that?

Comment: You need to use `renderEvent` remember event must be an Event Object with a title and start at the very least. `rerenderEvents` doesn't accepts any parameter

Comment: I tried renderEvent and still not working. Here's an example of event in my code: 
title: 'test',
id: 'id1',
start: '2014-02-10',
url: 'some url'

The console says:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasTime' of undefined

Comment: yes, `start: '2014-02-10'` for example.